# Ajax-assigned variable inaccessible after assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I have a script that fetches data from a SQL database and I'm trying to build a JS wrapper for it. I'm using the following functions to call that script and use information from the DB as soon as it's ready.

```
var User = function() {
    this.email = null;

    //Async call to get user values
    this.current(function(response) {
        this.email = response.email;

        //The value is assigned/usable at this point
    });
};

User.prototype.current = function(callback) {
    $.post("php/db_functions.php", {object: "CurrentUser"}).done(function(result) {
        callback(JSON.parse(result)[0]);
    });
};.
```

Everything seems to work fine, but if I try to access the value from the object after I've created it, it returns undefined, like so:

```
var me = new User();

//And then, way after the async call and when me.email should be defined
me.email //Returns undefined
```

Why can I use it in the callback, but not afterwards?

Comment: Because `$.post()` is **asynchronous**.

Comment: Knowing it's asynchronous isn't helpful on its own, given my problem was with context and not timing.

Comment: OK, apologies. That's an extremely common misunderstanding and it wasn't clear where that `new User()` call was being made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a function, the context variable `this` points to either the global `window` object or to `undefined` in the strict mode, unless specified otherwise by the caller. Therefore, you need to either capture the value of `this` in a local variable:

```
//Async call to get user values
var that = this;
this.current(function(response) {
    that.email = response.email;
});
```

or call the function in the desired context using either the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method:

```
User.prototype.current = function(callback) {
    var that = this;
    $.post("php/db_functions.php", {object: "CurrentUser"}).done(function(result) {
        callback.call(that, JSON.parse(result)[0]);
    });
};.
```

Also, as others have mentioned, there is no guarantee the AJAX request will have finished by the time the `User` contructor returns.

Comment: This works fine. Note to other answerers: I may have been unclear, but this was not a timing issue. I wasn't trying to access the value right after its assignment. The real problem is right here.

Comment: The behaviour of `this` can often be a major pain. In ECMAScript 6, a lambda expression syntax was added, which captures `this`, so what I described is no longer necessary: `this.current((response) => this.email = response.email);` Sadly, only Firefox supports these at the time of this comment.

Comment: It's misleading to say that a function's `this` points to the global object by default. It entirely depends on how the function is called.

Comment: Which is why I clarified that it only points to the `window` object *unless specified otherwise using either the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method, the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method or the dot notation*.

Comment: And what about bracket notation, `.bind`, `new` and strict mode? That's my point, there are so many "exceptions" that making the global variable reference the default is strange. Keep it simple and say that the value depends on how the function is called and in this specific case it points to `window` because the function is called traditionally like `x()`..

Comment: That's a fair point, I altered the answer (although [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) isn't really considered an exception, as it is / can be implemented using the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method).

Answer (score 1):

This is a timing bug since the variable is not assigned until the async call returns. You can't access email right away.